# Thunderbird typing very slow/lagging when replying to long thread

Tags: performance, thunderbird

When I reply to an email that has many (20 or so) previous replies, typing in the editor is painfully slow. There is a delay of ~5 seconds between keystrokes registering.

when I compose a new message, this problem is not evident.

Any help is appreciated!

Mozilla Thunderbird 3.1.8 with Lightning 1.0b2 on Ubuntu 10.04 (Lucid)

Comment: Do you have any extensions installed?

Comment: @random: Other than the Lightning 1.0b2 that I mentioned? No.

Comment: I got rid of lightning calendar and that seems to help for now...

Comment: I am running Thunderbird 52.3 and have this problem.  In fact, I've had this very problem for yeeeeeaaarrrrsssss.  I've tried every solution I could find and nothing helps.  I hate it.  But I still prefer Thunderbird to that dreadful Outlook.

Answer (score 1):

It happened to me with a previous 3.1x Thunderbird version. Maybe upgrade to 3.1.9. Might be some setting in html composing settings, or , I also noticed a boost when unmarked global index and search checkbox at Preferences/Advanced , General tab. Other things I did not try (as an update solved it) were deactivate grammar auto checking, use only non html composing, etc.

It might be that you have it configured as typing in text only mode, but there's a setting at composing settings, in preferences which give you several options, and default I think is type in html, rich format, if the original wrtitter was doing so. So would happen only in replies, not in a new blank message.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. For some reason, it doesn't seem to be behaving poorly anymore, and I haven't change a thing (not even a reboot). Very weird. I'll keep an eye on it and take your advice if it occurs again.

Answer (score 0):

If all of the above does not help, try what I did.
Windows explorer to C:\USERS
RIGHT click on your account and choose "Properties"
In the General tab, select the Advanced button
Uncheck the box "Allow files in this folder to have contents indexed in addition to file properties"
Select OK, and then select APPLY
When asked, allow this to apply this to all sub-folders. Click OK to close this window.
THIS WILL STOP THE HIDDEN APPS FOLDER FROM BEING INDEXED, WHICH WILL STOP WINDOWS FROM INDEXING YOUR EMAILS (which is the cause of the problem).
Next, go into your account folder and select just the folders you want indexed.
Repeat the above process of those folders (this time choosing to index the the folder and its sub-folders).
Ta da.   Worked like a charm for me.

Comment: sorry, nope.  that took an hour, and has no effect on the problem.

Comment: for me, the solution was to disable Windows Defender scanning on the Thunderbird profile folder, located under C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Thunderbird

Comment: None of these solutions solve it for me.  I want to cry.